# Proving the convergence of a series using the convergent difference

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say there is a convergent series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ and a series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n-b_n|$$ converges.

I'm looking to prove the convergence or disprove via example the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$

This is similar to another question I posted, but critically different in that the difference of the two series is given as convergent. This seems like a stronger condition that the limit of the difference being equal to 0. I tried using the comparison test, but it seems more useful for determining the convergence of $$|a_n - b_n|$$ than for determining the properties of b_n.

If a_n = 0, then it seems like b_n must converge, because the difference converges. The proof structure of this is stumping me.

Comment: I think the proof is a one-liner, if you apply one (or two) of the basic theorems about series. Like one of the first handful of theorems presented in an introductory chapter on Series in a calculus book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sum\left|a_n-b_n\right|$ converges, we know that $\sum(a_n-b_n)$ is absolutely convergent and thus convergent. We can then write

$$\sum b_n=\sum(a_n-a_n+b_n)=\sum a_n-\sum(a_n-b_n)$$

to deduce that $\sum b_n$ is the difference of two convergent series, so it also converges.